# how to draw route map using intent Android

Tags: android

My code is

```
public class RouteMap extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set up GUI
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Reference edit field
        final EditText addressfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        final EditText addressfield1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address1);
        // Reference search button
        final Button launchmapbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.launchmap);
        launchmapbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    // Get source address
                    String address = addressfield.getText().toString();
                    address = address.replace(' ', '+');
                    // Get Destination address
                    String address1 = addressfield1.getText().toString();
                    address1 = address1.replace(' ', '+');
                    // Prepare intent
                    Intent geoIntent = new Intent(
                            android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                    .parse("geo:0,0?q=" + address + ","
                                            + address1));
                    // Initiate lookup
                    startActivity(geoIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But I can't get the map between two places.

I want to get the route map between two places. The place entered using *EditText* by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + point1_lat + ","
                    + point1_lng + "&daddr=" + point2_latitude + "," + point2_longitude + ""));
startActivity(intent);
```

Or if you want to place mark then used below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("geo:55.74274,37.56577?q=55.74274,37.56577 (name)"));
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

try to mke something like the following :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

please give me some feedback

Hope that Helps .

Answer (score -1):

You can draw your route by making the following steps:
1-create list from type LatLng and add your navigation paths inside it
2- use code like the following 
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
    options.addAll("put your list here").color(Color.BLUE).width(4);
    Polyline navigateRoute = "your google map object".addPolyline(options);

Comment: The person specifically asked how to do this with an intent not how to draw the lines on the map directly.